# Merge statement error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am executing the following merge statement in SQL Server 2008:

```
MERGE 
PopulationData AS a
USING ImagesData AS b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.SURNAME = 'joe123'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(a.ID,a.SURNAME)
VALUES (12454,'joe123');
```

I have the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Can anyone tell me where the syntax error.

Comment: What happens if you add a semicolon before the `MERGE` keyword?? MERGE is one of those statements that insists on being the **first statement** in a T-SQL batch.... maybe you have other statements before this???

Comment: Thanks marc_s, the problem that i was executing the query on sql server management studio 2008 but i was connecting to sql server 2005 database on another server. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing your query in SQL Management Studio gives me the following error:

> Msg 10739, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 The insert column list used in
>   the MERGE statement cannot contain multi-part identifiers. Use single
>   part identifiers instead.

I then remove the identifiers...

```
MERGE 
PopulationData AS a
USING ImagesData AS b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.SURNAME = 'joe123'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(ID,SURNAME)
VALUES (12454,'joe123');
```

...and the query parses successfully. Therefore, the syntax error is almost certainly not coming from your MERGE statement. Are you really executing only the statement you posted, or is it part of a larger script or procedure? And if you double-click the error message, it should highlight the line where the syntax error is (at least with SQL 2008).

Update: I noticed that you have tagged the question for SQL 2005 and 2008, but MERGE is only supported in SQL 2008. Parsing the query under SQL 2005 gives the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's the query that i am executing and when double-click on the error message it highlight the line "PopulationData AS a"

Comment: If the PopulationData contains other not null fields, will this result to this error?

Comment: It looks like you are executing the query in a SQL 2005 database.

Comment: Thank you very much Pondlife. You are right, the sql server that i was connecting was 2005. my current sql management studio was 2008. I just connected to a 2008 database and it is working. Thanks again

Comment: @Joe123: You should probably [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") as it seems to have resolved all the issues pertaining to your question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i was executing the query on sql server management studio 2008 but i was connecting to sql server 2005 database on another server. Now it is fixed